# Bash-shell awk if-else with ternary operator grammar issue

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
cat file
AirIfLoadProfile trafficModelPrb ulDlRatioPerQci
EUtranCellTDD servOrPrioTriggeredErabAction 1
```

When I execute the command:

```
 awk '($NF!~/^[0-9]+$/)?{printf("%s,%s,%s",$1,$2.$3)}:{printf("%s,%s,%s",$1,$2,$3)}' file
```

It comes to the error below:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: ($NF!~/^[0-9]+$/)?{printf("%s,%s,%s",$1,$2.$3)}:{printf("%s,%s,%s",$1,$2,$3)}
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: ($NF!~/^[0-9]+$/)?{printf("%s,%s,%s",$1,$2.$3)}:{printf("%s,%s,%s",$1,$2,$3)}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                ^ syntax error
```

Please help me find the format issue.

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: AirIfLoadProfile trafficModelPrb.ulDlRatioPerQci
    EUtranCellTDD servOrPrioTriggeredErabAction 1

Comment: The result should be that when the $NF is not a number , it should display dot connect column 2 and column 3 as one column, if the $NF is a number ,the column 2 and column should separated by space

Comment: Include the output in your question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The right way:

```
awk '{ printf("%s %s%s%s\n",$1,$2,($NF~/^[0-9]+$/? " ":"."),$3) }' file
```

- the **3**rd format specifier `%s` accepts the result of the condition `($NF~/^[0-9]+$/? " ":".")`

---

The output:

```
AirIfLoadProfile trafficModelPrb.ulDlRatioPerQci
EUtranCellTDD servOrPrioTriggeredErabAction 1
```